# Android Spinner Control : Limit the Number of Items Visible in Dropdown

Tags: android

I want to hold numbers from 1 to 100 in a spinner drop down and limit the numbers of items visible to 3. All the other numbers should get by scrolling in the spinner dropdown.....please help

Comment: you looking for spinner or Piker? Because Spinner hold only one data at one time and Piker 3 data.

Comment: visible 3 data in the drop down all the other data in the dropdown should be scrollable

Answer (score 0):

There is no default method in spinner to control number of items to display in drop-down. But You can do this by setting customized adapter to spinner.

Comment: Kindly Refer setVisibleItemNo (int no) function  URL:https://github.com/ankitthakkar/DropDownSpinner